# How do I convert my Table into a Normalised structure?

Tags: database-design, android-sqlite

For my Game App, I have a table of Data (one of many)in CSV format.
It currently has 40+ columns, one for each Profession (fighter, rogue, wizard etc), and skill_name.

Each row (40+) contains the skill name, and a String representing the Cost of that skill for each profession.

A snippet from the original .csv contains data as shown here:

```
Skill,Fighter,Thief,Rogue
Armor-Heavy,2,4,3
Armor-Light,1,2,1
Armor-Medium,2,3,2
```

To enter this into a normalised database, I should have a Profession List table, a Skill List table, and a skill_costs_by_profession table.

I have built and populated the skill list and profession list tables:

```
CREATE TABLE "skills" ("_id" INTEGER, "skill" TEXT)

CREATE TABLE "professions" ("_id" INTEGER, "profession" TEXT)
```

I can create a table to hold the normalised data:

```
CREATE TABLE "skillCostByProfession" ("skill_id" INTEGER, "profession_id" INTEGER, "cost" INTEGER)
```

skillCostByProfession will have the data organised:

```
profession_id, skill_id, cost
1            |   1     |   2         (Fighter, Armor-Heavy, cost (2))
1            |   2     |   1         (Fighter, Armor-Light, cost (1))
1            |   3     |   2         (Fighter, Armor-Medium, cost (2))
2            |   1     |   4         (Thief, Armor-Heavy, cost (4))
2            |   2     |   2         (Thief, Armour-Light, cost (2))
2            |   3     |   3         (Thief, Armour-Medium, cost (3))
3            |   1     |   3         (Rogue, Armor-Heavy, cost (3))
3            |   2     |   1         (Rogue, Armour-Light, cost (1))
3            |   3     |   2         (Rogue, Armour-Medium, cost (2))
```

etc

I am struggling to find a way to put the data from the original .csv into the new skillCostByProfession table

I am using a combination of LibreOffice Calc and DB Browser (SQLite), to prepare the database for my Android App.

How can I convert the table of data I have into the format that I need, without writing the 1600 rows by hand?

Comment: Via SQL `update` which sets a table via a query. PS [mre]

Comment: @philipxy I need to completely change the structure of the table, not update entries.  I am not sure how to upload an example table into my question, and thought I had provided enough information.

Comment: You want new tables with different columns, UPDATE can set new tables to queries on old tables. Given the level of detail you gave I too "thought I had provided enough information". Without example code it is hard to describe what exactly you need & what exactly you can do. Also we can expect that once you get specific all steps you need will be faqs.

Comment: OK, I see now. Write a (set of/looped?) query to pull data and put into new table. I am not sure where to start on that, but I think I understand your meaning

Comment: We don't use loops querying relational DBs. Time to follow a published academic textbook on information modelling, the relational model & DB design & querying? (Manuals for languages & tools to record & use designs are not such textbooks.) (Nor are wiki articles or web posts.) PS Please give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as tabular initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation--that at least sets thing up & tries to a first thing & ask a specific question re being stuck.

Comment: You need to give DDL & example input values for (a minimal representative part of) your old design since it is input to what you want to do. And corresponding output values. And any other setup code, but it is best to keep to as little framework as possible, eg just SQL. [mre]

Comment: What you are basically trying to do is an unpivot operation.  It appears that Sqlite has no unpivot.  But a similar question and answer are shown  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42780565/turn-sqlite-columns-to-rows)

Comment: I did come across Unpivot. i might be able to find a platform I can use it in, to convert my tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend wrote me some python code, which does (almost) what I need.

```
filein=open("skills.csv","r")
fileout=open("out.txt","w")
professionline = filein.readline()
professions = professionline.rstrip().split(",")
for line in filein.readlines()[1:]:
    fields=line.rstrip().split(",")
    skill=fields[0]
    i=1
    for field in fields[1:]:
        cost=field
        if cost == "":
            cost = '0'      

        fileout.write("INSERT INTO skillCosts (skill_id, profession_id, cost) VALUES ((SELECT _id FROM skills WHERE category=\"{}\"), (SELECT _id FROM professions WHERE profession=\"{}\"), {});\n".format(skill, professions[i], cost))
        i+=1
```

This loads the .csv, and converts the top line (Profession Headers) into an array.
It then takes each row of Costs and creates an SQL Query.
This set of queries is written to a file (this example uses .txt, where I can copy/paste into DB Browswer's sql-input section)
It is possible to format a single Query to INSERT data, but my table goes over the 1,000 item limit.

Answer (score 1):

I took it as a personal chalange and wrote this pseudocode so you could adapt it:

```
public Dictionary professionsToID = new Dictionary<string, string>();

public  Dictionary skillsToID = new Dictionary<string, string>();

public void Main(string[] args)
{
        string newcsvfile = "path\tempfilename.csv";
        Dictionary d = prepare();
        WriteDictionaryToFile(newcsvfile,d);


        AddSkillsToDatabase("source.csv", CreateConnection())
        skillsToID = GetSkillsId();

        AddProfessionToDatabase("source.csv", CreateConnection())
        professionsToID = GetProfessionId();


        TextToReferences("source.csv", "destination.csv");
}

public Dictionary prepare()
{

    // Reading textfile line by line
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868369/how-to-read-a-large-text-file-line-by-line-using-java

    file = csv;

    List<String[]> actualCSVList = new List<String[]>
    String[][] actualCSVArr = new String[][]();


    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            // process the line.

            //fill columnvalues in an array wich represents a row
            String[] arrOfRow = line.split(",");

            //Add row to List
            actualCSVList.Add(arrOfRow);
        }

        //convert list to multidimensional array
        actualCSVArr = actualCSVList.toArray();


        for(int d1 = 0; d1 <= actualCSVList.count-1, d1++)
        {
            //loop lines

            String[] actualLine = actualCSVArr[d1];
            Dictionary <String, String> rows = new Dictionary <String, String>();

            string skill = "";
            string prof = "";


            for(int i = 0; i <= actualLine.lenght; i++)
            {
                //replace index with profession (or skill)

                switch(i)
                {
                    case 0:
                        skill = actualLine[i].ToString();
                    break;

                    case 1:
                        prof = "Fighter";
                    break;

                    case 2:
                        prof = "Thief";
                    break;

                    case 3:
                        prof = "Rogue";
                    break;
                }

                //is the case when i = 0
                if(!prof.Equals(""))
                {
                    // Add: profession, skill, cost => "profession|arrayindex","skill:cost"
                    rows.Add(prof + "|" + i.ToString(), skill + ":" + actualLine[i].ToString());
                }
            }
        }

    return rows;
}

void WriteDictionaryToFile(string filename, Dictionary dic)
{
    //Write to the new CSV
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string,string>  kvp in dic)
    {
        string prof = kvp.Key.Split("|")[0];

        string[] skillAndCost = kvp.Value.Split(":");

        string skill = skillAndCost[0];
        string cost = skillAndCost[1];

        string nline = prof + "," + skill + "," + cost;

        System.IO.File.WriteNewLine(filename, nline);
    }
}

void TextToReferences(string sourcefile, string destinationfile)
{
    // Reading textfile line by line
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868369/how-to-read-a-large-text-file-line-by-line-using-java

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(sourcefile)))
    {
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            // process the line.

            // 0=prof 1=skill 2=cost
            string[] arrline = line.Split(",");
            string prof = arrline[0];
            string skill = arrline[1];
            string cost = arrline[2];

            string nline = professionsToID[prof] + "," + skillsToID[skill] + "," + cost;

            System.IO.File.WriteNewLine(destinationfile, nline));
        }
     }
}

Dictionary GetSkillsId()
{
    //https://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_data/using-sqlite-in-a-c-application.html

    Dictionary dic = new Dictionary();
    SQLiteConnection sqlite_conn;
    sqlite_conn = CreateConnection();
    List<string> columnnames = ReadColumnnames(sqlite_conn);


    SQLiteDataReader sqlite_datareader;
    SQLiteCommand sqlite_cmd;

    foreach (string column in columnnames)
    {
        sqlite_cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "SELECT id FROM skills WHERE skill = column";

        sqlite_datareader = sqlite_cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (sqlite_datareader.Read())
        {
            string id = sqlite_datareader.GetString(0);
            dic.Add(column,id);
        }
    }
    conn.Close();


    return dic;
}

Dictionary GetProfessionsId()
{
    //https://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_data/using-sqlite-in-a-c-application.html

    Dictionary dic = new Dictionary();
    SQLiteConnection sqlite_conn;
    sqlite_conn = CreateConnection();
    List<string> columnnames = ReadColumnnames(sqlite_conn);


    SQLiteDataReader sqlite_datareader;
    SQLiteCommand sqlite_cmd;

    foreach (string column in columnnames)
    {
        sqlite_cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "SELECT id, profession FROM professions";

        sqlite_datareader = sqlite_cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (sqlite_datareader.Read())
        {
            string id = sqlite_datareader.GetString(0);
            string pro = sqlite_datareader.GetString(1);
            dic.Add(pro,id);
        }
    }
    conn.Close();


    return dic;
}

static SQLiteConnection CreateConnection()
{

    SQLiteConnection sqlite_conn;
    // Create a new database connection:
    sqlite_conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=
    database.db;Version=3;New=True;Compress=True;");
    // Open the connection:
    try
    {
        sqlite_conn.Open();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }

    return sqlite_conn;
}

static List<string> ReadColumnnames(SQLiteConnection conn)
{
    //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/685206/how-to-get-a-list-of-column-names/685212

    List<string> columnnames = new List<string>();

    SQLiteDataReader sqlite_datareader;
    SQLiteCommand sqlite_cmd;
    sqlite_cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "SELECT sql FROM sqlite_master WHERE tbl_name = 'table_name' AND type = 'table'";

    sqlite_datareader = sqlite_cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (sqlite_datareader.Read())
    {
    string myreader = sqlite_datareader.GetString(0);
    columnnames.Add(myreader);
    }
    conn.Close();

    return columnnames;
}

static SQLiteConnection CreateConnection()
{

    SQLiteConnection sqlite_conn;
    // Create a new database connection:
    sqlite_conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=
    database.db;Version=3;New=True;Compress=True;");
    // Open the connection:
    try
    {
    sqlite_conn.Open();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
    return sqlite_conn;
}

static void AddSkillsToDatabase(string sourcefile, SQLiteConnection conn)
{
    // Reading textfile line by line
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868369/how-to-read-a-large-text-file-line-by-line-using-java

    list<string> skills = new list<string>();

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(sourcefile)))
    {
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            // process the line.

            // 1=skill
            string[] arrline = line.Split(",");
            string skill = arrline[0];

            if(!skills.Contains(skill))
            {
                skills.Add(skill);
            }
        }
     }


    SQLiteCommand sqlite_cmd;
    sqlite_cmd = conn.CreateCommand();

    foreach(string s in skills)
    {
        sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO skills(skill) VALUES (s);";
        sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

}

static void AddProfessionToDatabase(string sourcefile, SQLiteConnection conn)
{
    // Reading textfile line by line
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868369/how-to-read-a-large-text-file-line-by-line-using-java

    list<string> professions = new list<string>();

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(sourcefile)))
    {
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            // process the line. Firstline are the professions

            string[] arrline = line.Split(",");

            foreach(string p = arrline)
            {
                professions.Add(p);
            }

            //TODO: remove firts entry

            break;
        }
     }


    SQLiteCommand sqlite_cmd;
    sqlite_cmd = conn.CreateCommand();

    foreach(string p in professions)
    {
        sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO professions(profession) VALUES (p);";
        sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

}
```

The solution to a good database is a good concept.
To ensure this you should always plan the database **before** you starting with coding it (i didn't do that everytime myself :D).

1. plan functionalities, windows and more
2. plan the database and ensure that you have all the values you need for the objects in step 1
3. create the database
4. Create queries wich you need for the planed objects from step 1
5. realize objects of step 1 and check if database and objects "match"

As an important starting point to plan the database you can create a diagram/scheme
[image: diagram]

For the scheme above i used Microsoft Visio (type "UML" in the Templatesearchbox and choose "UML-Datanotation").
You can find a lot of tools just search for "UML Tools" then you can search for the one wich matches your specifications.
You should look for a tool wich support your programming language because that ones mostly have nice features fitted on the language (f.e. design database diagram => create programmcode).

A few tools are:

- Microsoft Visio (only for drawing)
- modelio
- Visual Paradigm

(@all readers: can you add some tools?)

Maybe your IDE have some diagram features as well.

But you should take a look on UML (**U**nified **M**odeling **L**anguage) first.
Then you can decide wich program draw it like you like it most (or in the worst case draw diagrams by hand - sometimes its usefull if travel and have an idea).

Comment: Definitely interesting to see your approach, but I have 40+ columns  and 40+ rows (and multiple tables) to apply this to.

Comment: @BlackSpike I added some code to autofill the skills and professions in a table. Could you please add a scheme of your database so we can think on a complete solution.

Comment: The database is not fully built yet. So far, I have the 3 tables mentioned, and will be adding a "startingSkillsByCulture" table; as above, but with Skill and Culture (e.g. Nomad, Urban, MountainMen, etc), showing how many Ranks of a skill they start with.

I am still new to Databases, and am not sure what you require for a "schema", as it seems to be defined several ways

Comment: @BlackSpike I edited my answer. By scheme i ment something like a diagram to check the structure (look above).

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Your pic is pretty much what I am aiming for. Is there a simple tool for producing such a pic? (I can use Paint, but something more specific might be useful)

Comment: @BlackSpike I edited my answer. I can't recommend you a specific tool because i didn't used them often. But you should definitly look at UML, search for tools and decide wich is the best for your needs. (more details above)

Answer (score 0):

First, I’d like to say that’s your chosen solution would be the best.

I think you could solve it like this:

[image: Table Profession]

[image: Table Skills]

(The columns “light”, “medium”, “heavy” are to check if the “level” is available – so you don’t have to create them if every skill has this three “levels”)

[image: Table SkillCosts]

(Light, Medium, Heavy => content would be costs of “levels”)

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I feel you may have been misled by the Example table. I will not be splitting Armour into its separate types, as that is a level of detail too far, considering the rest of the Skill List.

Comment: @BlackSpike Do you have a second example for a skilltype? Because if you have 3 types of every skill you could simply made columns with title "first type, second type, third type"

Comment: A fair number of the Skills have Types, but not always 3: Outdoor.Animal, Outdoor.Environmental, ... Lore. Basic, Lore. Obscure ... Science.Basic, Science.Advanced ... But a fair few do not have Types: Crafting, Self Control, Urban, Influence, Communication. I have chosen to not split them down into Types, as it would introduce a level of detail I feel I do not need.

Comment: @BlackSpike Have you found a solution?

Comment: Yes. I posted my own answer: Python Script.